# Command prompt redirect to Arduino not working

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port, arduino

I have a simple Arduino program that parses an int from the serial input and opens a [solenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid). It works perfectly with the Arduino Serial Monitor (older Arduino, [Diecimila](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDiecimila) with ATmega168).

The goal I have is to send that data to the Arduino from the command prompt. I have already made sure the command prompt com settings are correct by running:

```
mode com7:9600,n,8,1
```

However, when I try to send it the integer for it to parse, nothing happens, for example:

```
ECHO 2 > COM7
```

I have also tried ECHO '2' > COM7, ECHO "2" > COM7, (ECHO 2) > COM7 and all the other variations I could think of.

*EDIT* Just to note, I have tried this with the Arduino Serial Monitor, [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), and [HyperTerminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperACCESS). All of these programs communicate with the Arduino just fine, and the solenoids open as expected. I have also tried the below code with `Serial.parseInt()` instead of `Serial.read()` and with and without the single quotes around the case numbers. Once again, in all cases it worked with the above three programs, but not with the command prompt.

*EDIT* Here is the sketch I am working with:

```
int incoming;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available > 0)
    {
        incoming = Serial.read();

        switch(incoming)
        {
            case '1':
                digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
                delay(2000);
                degitalWrite(2, LOW);
                break;
            case '2':
                digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
                delay(2000);
                degitalWrite(4, LOW);
                break;
            case '3':
                digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
                delay(2000);
                degitalWrite(6, LOW);
                break;
            case '4':
                digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
                delay(2000);
                degitalWrite(8, LOW);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I had no idea what to do, the above answers didn't work out, and I had a spare Arduino UNO on hand. I plugged the UNO into my relay board, uploaded the identical code, and now everything works from the command prompt AND the three above mentioned programs. Would anyone have any idea why this would behave differently with the same code on an UNO compared to a Diecimila? I was under the impression that the code should behave the same independent of the type of Arduino. Regardless, I will be using the UNO from here on out, as I need to communicate with it over the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

- Did you try `echo 2 > com7:` (note the colon)?
- The line delimiter in Windows is the two-byte sequence CR/LF. Perhaps the serial monitor uses another one and your Arduino sketch does not understand the CR/LF.

If that does not help you should post the sketch or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) example.

Comment: I have not tried the colon, I will give that a try as soon as I get home. I am pretty sure it is not the CR/LF sequence that is causing this issue, because I tried a CR/LF response when I opened the connection with PuTTY and everything still worked. So far the connection has worked with the Arduino Serial monitor, PuTTY, and HyperTerminal.

Comment: The colon after com7 did not change the results. I have tried all of the different line ending types in both the Arduino Serial Monitor and PuTTY and it worked in all instances. Any further ideas?